# Why do array elements seem to escape null checks?

Tags: c#

Apparently non-nullable is the new default so I went with it. Consider the following piece of code:

```cs
public class C { }
        
public static C f()
{
    return null;
}
```

The compiler warns for a possible null reference return. But if I write instead:

```cs
public static C f()
{
    C[] a = new C[10];
    return a[0]; // null
}
```

Then the compiler stays silent. I checked that the value returned is actually `null`. Is this just a weakness of the inference engine?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your array is declared as type `C[]` rather than `C?[]` - so the compiler expects that you know what you're doing and will populate the elements so they're non-null. It doesn't take into account that the default element values *will* be null. Detecting code to fully populate the array before reading any values would be extremely difficult or infeasible.

Whether you consider this a "weakness of the inference engine" or not is more of a matter of opinion; but basically you should be careful with arrays.